# Can I "park" the value of a non-refundable airline ticket?

Tags: air-travel, bookings, fees-and-charges, fares, united-airlines

I have a ticket on United (Economy "K" class) for a 2-week trip in January from Canada to the US. The ticket is non-refundable, but is changeable for a hefty fee ($200) and is valid for a year. The ticket is also marked "*0VALUAFTDPT - Cancel reservations before the scheduled departure time or TICKET HAS NO VALUE*"

Let's say I can't travel in January, and instead I want to take the same trip sometime in the summer.

Now, if I knew my exact travel dates in the summer, I could just pay the $200 fee (and any difference in airfare), and make the change.

However, what if I don't know my summer travel dates yet, and won't know them by my original January departure date? **Is it possible to cancel the January reservation now, and pick a new travel date much later, paying the $200 change fee only once?** I.e. can I "park" or "store" the value of the ticket without picking a new date right away?

Comment: Usually the duration of the credit is up to 1 year but change fees will still apply.

Comment: Well done @Karlson would you please weave that into an answer so we can up vote it?

Comment: @GayotFow If I could find the reference below I would have.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems (from United Airlines' website) that you may cancel your current reservation and make changes to it for the next year from the date of issue

> [Can I cancel my reservation on united.com?](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/content/help/managereservations.aspx)
>
> Yes, if your plans change
>   and you prefer not to change your itinerary immediately, you may
>   cancel the reservation and return to it later to make flight changes
>   for up to one year from the date of issue. A change fee may apply.

This may be the perfect solution to your situation.